# Une phrase dans les aventures de Tintin - sens de « sans doute »

Tags: verbes, adverbes

> Sans doute pour essayer de retrouver le papyrus tombé à la mer.

Ici, *sans doute* exprime-t-il un ton possible ou certain ?

De plus, *tomber* est un verbe transitif. Pourquoi utilise-t-on *tombé* au lieu de *tombant* ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Pour expliquer la nuance de « sans doute » il faudrait avoir plus de contexte. Tu peux éventuellement dire dans quel album ça se trouve.

Comment: En général il vaut mieux poser une seule question par « question ». Tu aurais pu en poser une pour *tombé* et une autre pour le sens de *sans doute*

Comment: @Laure *Les cigares du pharaon*, page 3. Tintin s'adresse à Philémon Siclone qui a laissé tomber à la mer un précieux papyrus, mais qui, une fois assis dans le canot de sauvetage pour aller le rechercher, a oublié pourquoi il ramait. Sacré Philémon... un *Tryphon* avant *Tournesol* ;-)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Oui, c'est cet album. Mais par contre, il a oublié pourquoi il ramait? Si c'est le cas, pourquoi il tient le manuscrit? Ce n'est pas celui tombé dans l'eau?

Comment: @Q.DU J'aurais du écrire "qui croit avoir laissé tomber à la mer...", pardon. Or, le bruit court que ce facétieux personnage ne serait pas précisément la personne la moins distraite du monde. Eh oui, il a paniqué pour rien et "embarqué" Tintin dans sa méprise (ce qui, à un autre niveau d'analyse, consiste à faire surgir l'aventure sur le chemin du héros, procédé classique s'il en est).

Comment: @RomainVALERI  Merci de votre commentaire pour ce BD magnifique. Franchement, ça m'a pris du temps pour comprendre ce que vous avez écrit. Votre vocabulaire était un défis pour moi. Bon, je doit continuer à faire des efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans :

> ... le papyrus tombé à la mer.

*tombé* est le participe passé du verbe « tomber » employé ici comme adjectif. On aurait pu écrire la même chose ainsi :

> ... le papyrus qui est tombé à la mer.

quand ces paroles sont prononcées **le papyrus est déjà** dans la mer.

Si on avait employé participe présent « tombant » :

> le papyrus tombant dans la mer

on voudrait dire que le papyrus n'est pas encore dans la mer, mais qu'il est en train de tomber dans la mer.

Par contre je ne comprends pas ce qui te fait parler de verbe transitif ici. D'abord ici *tomber* n'est pas employé de façon transitive et par ailleurs le choix entre « tombant » et « tombé » ne dépend pas de la transitivité du verbe.

---

Le sens le plus fréquent de la locution ***sans doute*** est l'expression d'une chose qu'on suppose exacte, mais sans en être sûr à 100 %, c'est synonyme de « probablement ». C'est sans doute ce qui est exprimé dans cette phrase de Hergé. Plus de contexte pourrait le confirmer.

Cette locution peut parfois être employée avec son sens propre, c'est à dire pour exprimer une certitude, mais cet emploi se rencontre peu de nos jours. Il peut servir dans une argumentation, par exemple ce petit dialogue :
- C'est formidable ce beau temps, on peut se baigner tous les jours.
- Sans doute, mais on va bientôt manquer d'eau.

Si on veut employer *sans doute* pour exprimer une certitude on renforce la locution avec *nul* ou *aucun* ou *moindre*.

> Il s'est jeté à l'eau sans aucun doute (sans nul doute / sans le moindre doute) pour essayer de retrouver le papyrus tombé à la mer.

Comment: C'est juste. Etrangement, l'expression *sans doute* peut signifier soit **sans doute** soit **avec doute**. Il faut avouer qu'il y a de quoi s'y perdre...

Comment: Dans l'exemple sur la baignade quotidienne, je comprends qu'il y a un doute exprimé sur le caractère formidable du beau temps.

Comment: @mouviciel Dans l'argumentation avec *mais*... ça veut dire *d'accord mais*, c'est synonyme de *certes*.